# Response.Cookies: How to append with expiration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, httpresponse

Using the following code in ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application:

```
var cookies = _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Response?.Cookies;

if (cookies != null && !_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
{
    cookies.Append(key, data);
}
```

**Question**

How to add cookie with expiration? `IResponseCookies` interface (and the internal underlying implementation `ResponseCookies`) lacks of such an `Append` overload. Is this intentional, to move in direction to LocalStorage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iresponsecookies.append?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IResponseCookies_Append_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_CookieOptions_) that takes an instance of [`CookieOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
cookies.Append(
    key,
    data,
    new CookieOptions { MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(1) });
```

This example sets the [`MaxAge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions.maxage?view=aspnetcore-3.1) property, but there's also the [`Expires`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions.expires?view=aspnetcore-3.1) property. See [this](https://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/) for more about the difference.